# Tabs without Appbar

Tags: flutter, dart, tabs, tabbar

I'm looking for some help with creating tab indicators in my flutter application. Specifically, I want to create an indicator that crosses over the tabs when one is selected - for example, if I select tab 3, the indicator should cross over the previous two tabs. Is there a way to achieve this?  Like below -

[image: Please see here to find what I want]

I tried. Tabs and content are fine, I didn't get the indicator as I would like.  What I get -

[image]

Code:

```
DefaultTabController(
  length: 5, // length of tabs
  initialIndex: 0,
  child: Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
    children: [
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
        child: Container(
          child: TabBar(
            isScrollable: true,
            labelColor: Color(0xff5f2dea),
            labelPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8, right: 5),
            indicatorColor: Color(0xff5f2dea),
            indicatorPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8, right: 5),
            unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black,
            tabs: [
              Tab(),
              Tab(),
              Tab(),
              Tab(),
              Tab(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
        child: Container(
          height: 1250,
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              border: Border(
                  top: BorderSide(color: Color(0xffababab), width: 0.4))),
          child: TabBarView(children: [
            Container(),
            Container(),
            Container(),
            Container(),
            Container(),
          ]),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using Custom `indicator` , which is created with the help of `Decoration`, and decoration needs `BoxPainter`.

```dart
class CustomIndicator extends Decoration {
  const CustomIndicator();

  @override
  BoxPainter createBoxPainter([VoidCallback? onChanged]) {
    return MyTabBarPainter();
  }
}

class MyTabBarPainter extends BoxPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Offset offset, ImageConfiguration configuration) {
    final rect = Rect.fromLTRB(
      0,
      configuration.size!.height - 10, //thickens of tabBar
      offset.dx + configuration.size!.width,
      configuration.size!.height,
    );
    canvas.drawRect(rect, Paint()..color = Colors.deepPurple);
  }
}
```

And provide it on

```dart
TabBar(
  indicator: CustomIndicator(),
```

[image]